# Exporting Sonarqube reports into Excel - based on major, minor and critical categories

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Is there a way to export Sonarqube reports into Excel - based on major, minor and critical categories?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the REST API, to query the data into JSON text and then export that JSON to a CSV file.

I used the command below to get a JSON response:

`http://xxxxx.xx.xxxx.com:9000/api/issues/search?componentRoots=test_xxx_xx&statuses=OPEN,REOPENED&pageSize=500&pageIndex=1`

Where `componentRoots` is the your sonar project name.

It gave all the issues in JSON and then I converted it in to a CSV.

Comment: Okay because of paging I now have 8 JSON files, how do I convert them into a single CSV file? That is the part you left out of your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The only way is to use the [api/issues/search](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search) web service

Answer (score 3):

I used <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools to create the report. Here is step by step solution:

1. Before opening Sonar report, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools in the browser tab (Refer screenshot). Click on **Network** tab. Initially it'll be empty:

   [image]
2. Open Sonar report in the same browser tab.
3. Now you have to select a request in URL column (Refer screenshot in point # 4). You've to select that request whose URL is of the format - **https://sonar:8443/api/issues/search?**. Base URL might be different depending upon the name of the server where you have hosted Sonar website.
4. Click on **Response** tab (Refer screenshot):

   [image]

   Copy the entire JSON data to clipboard. First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the contents.
5. JSON data that you got is in below format:
   [image]

   Data of all the issues is present inside **issues** key. It is of array type as it contains a list of issues. Paste the entire JSON data into any notepad editor and get the value of **issues** node. A sample **issues** node data is shown below:

   ```
   [
   {
   "key":"AYMBNpviy48WWZHdsU1Z"
   ,"rule":"OWASP:UsingComponentWithKnownVulnerability"
   ,"severity":"MAJOR"
   ,"component":"B91661CE-50F8-45CB-8F54-29CD044EF32D"
   ,"project":"B91661CE-50F8-45CB-8F54-29CD044EF32D"
   ,"flows":[]
   ,"status":"OPEN"
   ,"message":"Filename: jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js | Reference: CVE-2021-41184 | CVSS Score: 6.1 | Category: CWE-79 | jQuery-UI is the official jQuery user interface library. Prior to version 1.13.0, accepting the value of the `of` option of the `.position()` util from untrusted sources may execute untrusted code. The issue is fixed in jQuery UI 1.13.0. Any string value passed to the `of` option is now treated as a CSS selector. A workaround is to not accept the value of the `of` option from untrusted sources."
   ,"author":""
   ,"tags":["cve","cwe","cwe-937","owasp-a9","vulnerability"]
   ,"transitions":["confirm"]
   ,"actions":["set_tags","comment","assign"]
   ,"comments":[]
   ,"creationDate":"2022-08-18T06:35:49+0100"
   ,"updateDate":"2022-08-18T06:35:49+0100"
   ,"type":"VULNERABILITY"
   ,"branch":"sonarqubepr"
   ,"scope":"MAIN"
   ,"quickFixAvailable":false
   },
   {
   "key":"AYMBNpviy48WWZHdsU1_"
   ,"rule":"OWASP:UsingComponentWithKnownVulnerability"
   ,"severity":"MAJOR"
   ,"component":"B91661CE-50F8-45CB-8F54-29CD044EF32D"
   ,"project":"B91661CE-50F8-45CB-8F54-29CD044EF32D"
   ,"flows":[]
   ,"status":"OPEN"
   ,"message":"Filename: jquery.ui.datepicker-ml.min.js | Reference: CVE-2021-41183 | CVSS Score: 6.1 | Category: CWE-79 | jQuery-UI is the official jQuery user interface library. Prior to version 1.13.0, accepting the value of various `*Text` options of the Datepicker widget from untrusted sources may execute untrusted code. The issue is fixed in jQuery UI 1.13.0. The values passed to various `*Text` options are now always treated as pure text, not HTML. A workaround is to not accept the value of the `*Text` options from untrusted sources."
   ,"author":""
   ,"tags":["cve","cwe","cwe-937","owasp-a9","vulnerability"]
   ,"transitions":["confirm"]
   ,"actions":["set_tags","comment","assign"]
   ,"comments":[]
   ,"creationDate":"2022-08-18T06:35:49+0100"
   ,"updateDate":"2022-08-18T06:35:49+0100"
   ,"type":"VULNERABILITY"
   ,"branch":"sonarqubepr"
   ,"scope":"MAIN"
   ,"quickFixAvailable":false
   }
   ]
   ```
6. The JSON array data obtained in previous step is of real use. Convert this JSON array data into an EXCEL file using any online converter. I used the following website - https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

**What if my report has more than one page?**

Sonar loads 100 records per page. To get the next page you've to click on <kbd>Show More</kbd> button at the bottom:

[image]

Every time you click on the <kbd>Show More</kbd> button, a new request goes to the Sonar server which will show up in the <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tool's **Network** tab. So for all subsequent pages, repeat same set of steps to create a new Excel sheet per page. Then merge all the Excel sheets manually to create single master report.

**Note**: While merging the Excel files, remember that every Excel file will have a header row at the top. While merging the files, you'll have to keep the header row from from the first Excel sheet and ignore from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the REST APIs provided with SonarQube to query. The documentation of APIs is also embedded into every Sonar instance as different versions expose different APIs. 
We use Python for similar work as response will be in JSON and it will be easier to manipulate. Once you have arrived extracted issues of your liking, write them into .CSV or excel.

Link to web services will be in footer of Sonar Instance.

PS: Expanded answer to offset short-sighted answering. What is provided here is only abstract and not complete answer with query details.

**Not recommended by community**
With DB:- If you have been using Sonar for long and if you won't upgrade SQ too often you can choose to study table structure and understand how data is organised. We have done this too, but it gets messier with every passing upgrade (more inner queries). Cost of querying will be saved on bulk process of data as ES is not involved

Comment: @janos honestly the guy questioning didn't seem to do any home work so, the answer was incomplete. I take the blame that I didn't take broader community that will refer the answer in future

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command to get all issues in JSON format. Then you may consider to parse output by using jason parser programs.

> Replace "XXX:XXX" with Sonar Key defined in "sonar.projectKey" variable on "sonar-project.properties.txt" file

```
http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?componentKeys=XXX:XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can use the api. To get all the Issues in one go, use Postman:

```
GET: http://localhost:9099/api/issues/search?components=<project-key>&ps=500
```

where ps is Page Size.

You need to pass the Authorization. Use Type as Basic Auth. Provide username password that you used at the time of login. This will reduce time of downloading 100 records and then merging them into single excel.